# Calling a jQuery plugin without specifying any elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Say I have the following jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function () {
    //plugin code
}
```

Normally, you call a plugin on a certain number of elements, like such:

```
$("body").myPlugin();
```

---

Is there any way I can call my plugin without specifying an element?

I have tried calling it like such: `$.myPlugin();`, but that does not work.

What works is this: `$().myPlugin();`, but is that the correct way to invoke it?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The **quick** way to write it is this:

```
$.myPlugin = function () {
    // Plugin code
}
```

The **right** way to write it is this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.extend({
        myPlugin: function () {
            // plugin code
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

It might seem a little confusing at first, but it's a common jQuery pattern.

```
(function($){
     // Code
})(jQuery);
```

This code creates an anonymous function and calls it passing `jQuery` as argument. Inside the function this argument is bound to `$`. The reason this is done it that it allows you to work with the `$` even if jQuery is running in [no-conflict](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) mode.

The second part is [`$.extend`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.extend). It basically extends the jQuery object itself, when called with a single argument.

Calling the plugin (in the quick and the right case) is:

```
$.myPlugin();
```

Comment: I know about that pattern :)  I just didn't use it in the question to avoid code cluttering.  But thanks for the extend method!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for jQuery.extend() :

```
jQuery.extend({
    func: function() {
        alert('test');
    }
});
$.func();
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it *use* the collection if you write something different, like `$('a').myPlugin()`? If it doesn't, then why are you putting it in `$.fn`? Maybe you wanted to inject it into `jQuery` itself.

If it *does* work on a collection, but sometimes an empty collection makes sense, then I think that your invocant should be `$([])` -- passing an empty `Array` to `jQuery` gives you an empty collection; passing nothing at all seems to give you a collection containing `document`.

Comment: No it doesn't need any elements to work on; that's why I need it to be called without any elements

Comment: So I should change it to `$.myPlugin = function ()` instead of using the `fn` ? because I tried it now like that, and I can infact call it then with the notation I want: `$.myPlugin();`

Comment: And if I use `$.myPlugin = function ()`, will it still technically be called a `plugin` ?