# Minimal modifications to jQuery plugin sample to call plugin with no elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I essentially have the same goal as in this question:

[Calling a jQuery plugin without specifying any elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758370/calling-a-jquery-plugin-without-specifying-any-elements)

*However* I am looking for the minimal edit to add a method to the "conclusion" built up in the jQuery plugin guide...which culminates in a jQuery "data" based tooltip plugin:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

I'm looking for the turnkey "right" way to add a method (the sort that finds its place in the list with `reposition`, `show`, `hide`, and `update`) for something that could be called with no elements.  My case is I want to add a debug mode method you can call like:

```
$.tooltip('debug', true);
```

Like the author of the question I cite, I can get this working just fine with a parallel to:

```
$().tooltip('debug', true);
```

But the supplied answer wasn't cast in terms of the full-on `.data`-based tooltip plugin structure.  So I can't quite figure out where to inject the offered advice of using `.extend`.  Can anyone suggest the minimal edit to get the desired effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at this a bit, I think the simplest modification to do is just to inject the extend call right after the `$.fn.tooltip = function(method) { ... }` and make it a synonym, like this:

```
$.extend({
    tooltip: $.fn.tooltip
});
```

That seems to do the trick...and in the plugin's methods you just test to see if `this` is equal to `jQuery` (or `$`) to see if it's actually being called on "nothing".